# What is the Linux Stack?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I recently ran into a bug with the "linux stack" and the "linux stack size".  I came across a blog directing me to try

```
ulimit -a
```

to see what the limit for my box was, and it was set to `8192kb` which seems to be the default.

What is the "linux stack"? How does it work, what does it store, what does it do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: a stack overflow may appear with too deep (or infinite) recursion. Or perhaps by abuse of `alloca` (or equivalent, like variable length arrays) in C code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671423/stack-allocation-for-process | http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux/239323#239323

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is:

When programs on your linux box run, they add and remove data from [the stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) on a regular basis as the programs function.  The stack size, referes to how much space is allocated in memory for the stack.  If you increase the stack size, that allows the program to increase the number of routines that can be called.  Each time a function is called, data can be added to the stack (stacked on top of the last routines data.)

Unless the program is a very complex, or designed for a special purpose, a stack size of 8192kb is normally fine.  Some programs like graphics processing programs require you to increase the size of the stack to function.  As they may store a lot of data on the stack.

Feel free to increase the stack size for those applications, its not a problem.  To do so, use

`ulimit -s bytes`

BTW, [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I've been getting a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error in a Ruby app and wanted to get a better understanding of the fundamentals before I kept investigating.