# Where is the stack memory allocated from for a Linux process?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

We know that when a process is created,one stack is allocated for this process.The size of the stack is typically 8 Mb in linux.My question is that,from where this stack is allocated??From user space or from system space?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux

Answer (score 6):

I hope you know the concept that all user process will be kept in user space only. It uses system calls to get some work done by kernel.

The stack memory will be part of process context area in memory. i.e **user space**.

Suppose your process is running, get the PID by `ps -ax`. say 1234 is your PID.

`cat /proc/1234/maps` will give you the mapping of that particular process.

In thats maps file, you can check the `stack` for stack mapping.

Comment: your answer gives great insight as I was not aware of these. I have a small clarification.. How does the stack size is decided (we typically say 8 mb) ? Is it always 8mb?

Comment: `ulimit -s` will gives your default stack size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471564/what-does-ulimit-s-unlimited-do for more. :)

Comment: But when one process comes in existence then one kernel stack is allotted for it.So this process stack and kernel stack are same or different?

Answer (score 5):

First you must understand what paging and page faults are: [How does x86 paging work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work)

**Kernel vs process memory**

The Linux Kernel reserves two zones of virtual memory:

- one for kernel memory
- one for programs

The exact split is configured by `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_...`. By default:

- on 32-bit:

  - the bottom 3/4 is program space: `00000000` to `BFFFFFFF`
  - the top 1/4 is kernel memory: `C0000000` to `FFFFFFFF`

  Like this:

  ```
  ------------------ FFFFFFFF
  Kernel
  ------------------ C0000000
  ------------------ BFFFFFFF


  Process


  ------------------ 00000000
  ```
- on 64-bit: currently only 48-bits are actually used, split into two equally sized disjoint spaces. The Linux kernel just assigns:

  - the bottom part to processes `00000000 00000000` to `008FFFFF FFFFFFFF`
  - the top part to the kernel: `FFFF8000 00000000` to `FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF`

  Like this:

  ```
  ------------------ FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
  Kernel
  ------------------ FFFF8000 00000000


  (not addressable)


  ------------------ 008FFFFF FFFFFFFF
  Process
  ------------------ 00000000 00000000
  ```

**Process address space**

Simplified program *virtual* memory of a process:

```
------------------ <--- Top of the process address space
Stack (grows down)
v v v v v v v v v
------------------

(unmapped)

------------------ <--- Maximum stack size.


(unmapped)


-------------------
mmap
-------------------


(unmapped)


-------------------
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
brk (grows up)
-------------------
BSS
-------------------
Data
-------------------
Text
-------------------

------------------- <--- Bottom or process address space.
```

**Stack allocation**

The kernel maintains a list of pages that belong to each process, and synchronizes that with the paging.

If the program accesses memory that does not belong to it, the kernel handles a page-fault, and decides what to do:

- if it is above the maximum stack size, allocate those pages to the process
- otherwise, send a SIGSEGV to the process, which usually kills it

More info at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux/239323#239323

**`brk` and `mmap`**

Those system calls allow processes to explicitly request chunks of memory to the kernel instead of just going down the stack and segfaulting.

Here is a practical example of `brk`: [What does brk( ) system call do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-brk-system-call-do/31082353#31082353)

This answer explains the advantage of using the stack when that is possible: [What is the function of the push / pop instructions used on registers in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass/33583134#33583134)

**Physical memory**

There is no clear split between kernel and userspace memory: [Is there an explict split between userspace and kernel in physical memory on Linux x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471742/physical-memory-userspace-kernel-split-on-linux-x86-64)

Answer (score 3):

As others said, the stack is allocated in user space. But here are more details about this, in particular about its size and its growth.

8 MB is actually not the stack size, but the *maximum* stack size. A small part is initially allocated and the kernel grows the stack automatically when needed (after a page fault), keeping it below the stack size limit. If you do a memory access above the limit, you'll get a segmentation fault. But even if you do not reach this limit, this means that you might exhaust the physical memory (RAM + swap) just by filling the stack.

Here's a reference I've given in my answer to [How does stack allocation work in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux): Mel Gorman's paper [Understanding The Linux Virtual Memory Manager](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/pdf/understand.pdf). See in particular Section 4.6.1 *Handling a Page Fault*, with the exception "Region not valid but is beside an expandable region like the stack" and the corresponding action "Expand the region and allocate a page". See also D.5.2 *Expanding the Stack*.

Answer (score 0):

The stack memory required for application software is allocated from the user space.