# How do I find the range(s) of MMAPable virtual addresses in a program?

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap, allocation, virtual-memory

Background information:

1. I'm using 64 bit Arch on an x86 system.
2. I'm not using libc or any language that depends on libc. I'm using a proprietary research language. I am making my syscalls through inline assembly.
3. I'm writing an experimental custom allocator for a research project, so a portable solution is a nice-to-have, but not a requirement.
4. My programs are statically linked and I am willing and able to rewrite the libraries I'm using to account for a given solution.

According to this SO post: [Where is the stack memory allocated from for a Linux process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671423/where-is-the-stack-memory-allocated-from-for-a-linux-process) A program's virtual address space is organized like this:

```
------------------ <--- Top of the process address space
Stack (grows down)
v v v v v v v v v
------------------

(unmapped)

------------------ <--- Maximum stack size.


(unmapped)


-------------------
mmap
-------------------


(unmapped)


-------------------
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
brk (grows up)
-------------------
BSS
-------------------
Data
-------------------
Text
-------------------

------------------- <--- Bottom or process address space.
```

Presuming this is correct, I'm trying to find the range of MMAPable addresses between brk and the stack.

Is it sufficient to find the lower bound by getting a ptr from `sbrk(0)`, page aligning the ptr upwards, and then ensuring that `brk` and `sbrk` are never called again?

Is it sufficient to safely approximate the upper bound by getting a ptr to some location on the stack, getting the max size of the stack from `getrlimit`, subtracting that from the ptr, page aligning the ptr downwards, and then ensuring the size of the stack is never changed by `setrlimit`?

I don't need an exact range here, but I do need a large contiguous range of addresses that are guaranteed to be safely MMAPable(presuming I don't clobber them myself, of course). During my research I came across this: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=memory-understanding-mapping , which says:

> For 64-bit processes, two sets of address ranges with the process address space are available for mmap or shmat mappings. The first, consisting of the single range 0x07000000_00000000-0x07FFFFFF_FFFFFFFF, is available for both fixed-location and variable-location mappings. The second set of address ranges is available for fixed-location mappings only and consists of the ranges 0x30000000-0xCFFFFFFF, 0xE0000000-0xEFFFFFFF, and 0x10_00000000-0x06FFFFFF_FFFFFFFF. The last range of this set, consisting of 0x10_00000000-0x06FFFFFF_FFFFFFFF, is also made available to system loader to hold program text, data and heap, so only unused portions of the range are available for fixed-location mappings.

This is the exact kind of information I need, but it's for the wrong OS. If anyone can help me find this same information about Linux in general and Arch specifically, then that would be a great help.

Comment: Just call `mmap` with address NULL, the kernel will pick up a suitable address.

Comment: That is how my other custom allocators work. This one needs to be opinionated about where things go.

Comment: One approach is to `mmap` a very large `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE` region up front, passing address `NULL` to let the kernel pick the address.  Then you know you can safely create `MAP_FIXED` mappings within that address region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing I've found the solution I proposed in the question does work. I've been using `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` to check my custom allocator, and it's behaving as I expected. To reiterate the solution:

1. To find the lower bound use `sbrk(0)`, make sure the ptr is page aligned, and then ensure that `brk` and `sbrk` are never called again.
2. To safely approximate the upper bound find the stack size with `getrlimit`, subtract that from a ptr into the stack, page align the ptr, and then never change the stack size with `setrlimit`.

If you might need to touch `brk`, `sbrk`, or `setrlimit`, then you can also add some padding to the lower bound and subtract some padding from the upper bound. You can dynamically compute a safe amount of padding by finding how much memory the system has with `/proc/meminfo`, or if you don't need a general solution you can just over-approximate how much you'll need based on what you're doing.